# Is there any value $n$ such that the number of sets of size $n$ is neither $0$ nor $1$ nor $\infty$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Please let me know if you think that my question is not well-defined.

Is there any value $n$ such that the number of sets of size $n$ is neither $\color\red0$ nor $\color\red1$ nor $\color\red\infty$?

A few examples:

- For size $n=\frac12$, there are $\color\red0$ sets of this size
- For size $n=0$, there is exactly $\color\red1$ set of this size: $\emptyset$
- For size $n=\infty$, there are $\color\red\infty$ly many sets of this size:

  - $\mathbb{N}$
  - $\mathbb{R}$
  - $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{N}$
  - $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$
  - $\{2n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  - $\{2^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  - $\dots$

Can it be proved that no value of $n$ yields a different number of sets of size $n$?

Comment: Let $A$ be one set of size $n$. Consider $A\times\{b\}$ for various $b$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Not sure I got it. Could you give a more concrete example please?

Comment: Okay, let me phrase it a bit differently. Suppose there is a set of size $n$, call it $A$. For any (say, set) $b$, consider the set which consists of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$. It will then have the same size as $A$.

Comment: The question is, what is "the same" set for you? Must two sets which are "the same" must have the same elements or must they only be "isomorphic" in the sense that there is a bijection between them?

Comment: @Wojowu: Right, but there are $\color\red\infty$ly many sets of this size, so it does not quite answer my question.

Comment: @sigmabe: The same elements. And I doubt that it would made a difference in the question even if chose the other definition.

Comment: Ok, I also think there is no differerence for your question, but I want to have this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely defined.

For starters, "size" is only relevant when you consider cardinals. $\frac12$ is no more a cardinal, than `a` is a letter of the Hebrew alphabet. You could argue that there are no words in Hebrew which start with the letter $\pi$, as well. And you'd be technically right, but the question comes off as odd. Simliarly, $\infty$ is not a cardinal either, and what you might mean is "infinite".

To your question, if I understand it correctly: Yes, there is exactly one empty set; and for every other *cardinal* there is a proper class of different sets: if $A$ is a set of certain size, then $A\times\{0\}\neq A$ and they are equipotent. So for any non-empty cardinal there are so many sets of that cardinality, they don't even form a collection we can measure its size (technically, anyway).

Comment: OK, so at least my hunch in the opening statement was for a good reason... Thanks :)